# How do I install a fresh copy of Windows onto a new computer?

Tags: windows, media, license, windows-activation

I'm going to buy a new Acer nettop computer with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. It has no optical disc drive.

It will be full of pre-installed bloatware.

I want to format the hard disk drive and install a fresh copy of Windows.

I've found device drivers at Acer's web site. That's not a problem.

Where can I download a copy of the Windows installation media? Will I have any licensing or activation issues? Can I boot and install from a USB flash drive?

Comment: [Here](http://www.blogsdna.com/2016/how-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-drive-without-windows-7-iso-dvd.htm) is a link that steps through creating a Windows 7 bootable USB drive installer. It does assume you already have a disk image of the Windows 7 installation media. As for getting the media, each copy of the code is sold and licensed with its own installation key. I am unsure if there is a direct distribution method for the installation media from MS or not. You might try checking on the website for the manufacturer of the netbook to see if they supply replacement media.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-usb-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-using-windows-7-dvdusb-tool/

its quite simple, just need another machine and run the MS tool to put it on the thumbdrive

*and make sure you have the thumbdrive selected as a boot device in you bios

Comment: This answer links to Windows downloads from Microsoft. http://superuser.com/questions/78761#216398

Answer (score 0):

Acer website:

> [How do I reinstall the Operating System on my netbook?](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2631)
>
> If you do not have a set of Acer
>   Recovery Media you may purchase
>   recovery media online.

I don't know the cost.

I don't know if that's a download or a disc in the mail.

I don't know if that gets you a plain (crapware-free) Windows installation.